# Responsive overlapping issue

Tags: css, responsive-design, overlapping

I have the following issue..

I'm trying to place an image in my header. However, every time I try to view the website from a handheld device (eg. mobile phone) the image that I've placed is overlapping with my logo...

```
 <style>
        #babypic{              
         position: absolute;
         max-width: 200px;
         height: auto;
         left: 0;
         top: 111px; 
        }                
      </style>
     <div id="babypic">
      <img src={{ 'baby2.png' | asset_url }}>
      </div>
```

The following screenshots might help you to understand my issue better:
[image]
[image]

As you can see in the first pic, the baby is in perfect position. However, when I'm trying to reduce the window or access the site from mobile phone the baby overlaps with the logo as shown in the second picture.

Comment: did you use media query?

Answer (score 0):

you should resize the baby pics or increase the header height and change the style  #babypic{
         position: absolute;
         max-width: 200px;
         height: auto;
         left: 0;
         bottom: 0px; 
        }

in case the baby picture is on bottom.